# Free C++ library implementing hierarchical clustering or alike

Tags: gratis, library, c++, data-analysis, clustering

Which can cluster small number of points by the given maximum distance between them.

Two dimensions only.

Answer (score 0):

This library was utilized finally https://github.com/cdalitz/hclust-cpp

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/67227)